# Why is robots.txt being requested along with every Express GET?

Tags: node.js, express, robots.txt

I am using the the "Getting started" tutorial for Express from the expressjs.com website.

I am running my application (in Windows) as:

```
> set DEBUG=express:* & npm start
```

When I make a request to the server (in this example, `http://localhost:3000/`), I see in the console:

```
  express:router dispatching GET / +24s
  express:router query  : / +3ms
  express:router expressInit  : / +2ms
  express:router logger  : / +3ms
  express:router jsonParser  : / +3ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : / +4ms
  express:router cookieParser  : / +3ms
  express:router serveStatic  : / +1ms
  express:router router  : / +5ms
  express:router dispatching GET / +2ms
  express:view require "jade" +3ms
  express:view lookup "index.jade" +467ms
  express:view stat "C:\mysites\app\views\index.jade" +3ms
  express:view render "C:\mysites\app\views\index.jade" +3ms
GET / 304 545.682 ms - -
  express:router dispatching GET /robots.txt +58ms
  express:router query  : /robots.txt +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /robots.txt +3ms
  express:router logger  : /robots.txt +3ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /robots.txt +3ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /robots.txt +8ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /robots.txt +1ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /robots.txt +2ms
  express:router dispatching GET /stylesheets/style.css +19ms
  express:router query  : /stylesheets/style.css +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /stylesheets/style.css +1ms
  express:router logger  : /stylesheets/style.css +4ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +7ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +4ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +2ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /stylesheets/style.css +2ms
  express:router router  : /robots.txt +1ms
  express:router dispatching GET /robots.txt +1ms
GET /robots.txt 304 55.631 ms - -
```

I'm trying to understand who is triggering the GET request for `robots.txt` each time I make any page/resource request. I don't believe it's the browser. And it's not in the rendered page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Express</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Express</h1><p>Welcome to Express</p></body></html>
```

Is the `robots.txt` request something node.js/express is generating internally, perhaps only in this debug mode? If so, why?

My package.json file, in case it helps:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This was not related to node.js or express. I had recently installed the Wappalyzer Chrome extension. This was the first localhost site I worked on since then. When I turned off Wappalyzer I stopped seeing the requests for robots.txt. It makes sense that Wappalyzer is making this request, and that it doesn't show up as a normal request in the Chrome debugger.

Leaving this here on the off chance someone else has the same confusion when debugging an Express app.